# How can I use LINQ to find the Intersect between two properties of the same collection?

Tags: linq, intersect

Given an `IList<Foo>` with a data set that looks like this:

```
ID   CHILD  PARENT TYPE  
1   102    101    UPSELL  
1   103    101    UPSELL  
2   102    101    BONUS  
2   104    103    BONUS  
3   102    101    BONUS  
4   102    101    PRODUCT  
4   104    102    PRODUCT
```

How can I use LINQ to find a child which has a parent with the same ID?

Desired output is

```
ID   CHILD  PARENT TYPE 
4   102    101    PRODUCT
```

Comment: @everyone: He is asking for the pairings (child, parent) that occur within every ID (though I don't know why the output also contains an ID).  @aponzani: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The desired output doesn't seem to match what you're asking for, or what BlueRaja described.  It's not hard to find all (child,parent) pairs that occur in all IDs.  But the output of that would contain neither ID nor TYPE, because those are not common.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.  I grouped by ID first so I could process each group individually, but there's probably a way to combine it into a single query.

```
var grouping = foos.GroupBy(f => f.ID);
foreach(var g in grouping)
{
    var result = (from f1 in g from f2 in g where f1.Child == f2.Parent select f1);
    if( result.Any())
    {
        // you have your answer
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the GroupBy and the foreach so far, but it was the nested froms that I hadn't tried.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for managing to figure out the question. I used your answer to reverse-engineer what the question was :) . I've now updated the question so that it makes sense.